# Why isn't this jQuery working? Image fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I've got a class of `photoshow` in my css. They're images. I want them to fade out and fade back in when the page loads. Any The first lines with the `wysihtml5` work fine.  Any ideas?

console error:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

s

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).wysihtml5();
  });


  $('.photoshow').fadeOut().fadeIn('slow');

})
```

Here's the HTML

```
<%= link_to 'Back', :back %> <br>
  <%#= @photo.name %>
  <div class="photoshow">
    <%= image_tag @photo.image.url, width: '500', class: 'photoshow' %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Should work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zD7t5/

Comment: Interesting. I don't know what's going on here. :(

Comment: Open your console (F12) and check for errors ?

Comment: Just updated original post with error message

Comment: what about $('.photoshow').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).fadeIn('slow'); }) ? Is there a difference between chainig and using complete callback ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: I don't think your console error message is related to your issue by the way.

Comment: The console error is not relevant, it's a standard error from jQuery. In this case chaining or callbacks shouldn't matter, they should work the same, so something else is going on ?

Comment: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` that's not an error, that's a warning ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try a similar approach:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hides the picture so no one can see it
    $('.photoshow').hide(0);

    $('.wysihtml5').each(function(i, elem) {
        $(elem).wysihtml5();
    });

    // Fades the picture in
    $('.photoshow').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: This had no effect. Something else's going on.